# Member function reference qualified return type

Tags: c++, c++11

Reading Meyers new book I found something very similar to this:

```
// compile with
// g++-4.8 --std=c++11 -Wall   main3.cc && ./a.out
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Widget
{
    public:
        using DType = std::vector<int>;


        DType& data() &  // lvalue
          { 
            std::cout << "data (lvalue)    : " << &data_[0] << std::endl; 
            return data_; 
          };

        DType data() &&  //  rvalue
          { 
            std::cout << "data (rvalue)    : " << &data_[0] << std::endl; 
            return std::move(data_);  
          }; 

        // Please Note
        // int parameter is here to make the overloading possible
        // in a single class
        DType&& data(int) && 
          { 
            std::cout << "data (rvalue ref): " << &data_[0] << std::endl; 
            return std::move(data_);  
          }; 
    private:
        DType data_ { 0 };
};

Widget getWidget() { return Widget(); }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Widget w1;
    std::vector<int> d1 = w1.data();
    std::cout << "d1 copied        : " << &d1[0] << std::endl;

    std::vector<int> d2 = getWidget().data();
    std::cout << "d2 moved         : " << &d2[0] << std::endl;

    std::vector<int> d3 = getWidget().data(0);
    std::cout << "d3 moved         : " << &d3[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My point is very simple:
On my box as I would expect I have these results

```
data (lvalue)    : 0x8e28008
d1 copied        : 0x8e28018
data (rvalue)    : 0x8e28028
d2 moved         : 0x8e28028
data (rvalue ref): 0x8e28038
d3 moved         : 0x8e28038
```

So first vector was copied while the second and third were moved.

You can have two different signature to achieve move operation:

One returning an rvalue

```
DType data() &&  //  rvalue
```

and one returing a rvalue reference

```
DType&& data() &&
```

They achieve the same result: are there any differences I cannot see ? What is the "best" one?

Answer (score 2):

> You can have two different signature to achieve move operation:

That is wrong.

The first signature, the one returning `DType`, performs a move into the return value. The second signature, the one returning `DType&&` simply returns a reference. It doesn't move anything.

The move happens in the other code, specifically the part with `std::vector<int> d3 =`. Initializing a vector from an xvalue performs a move. That is what does the move, not the function. *However*, other kinds of operations won't perform a move:

```
// no move, just binding the member to a reference
std::vector<int>&& d3 = getWidget().data(0);
```

Using the first function, however, the move always happens:

```
// move into a temporary, and bind *that* to a reference
std::vector<int>&& d2 = getWidget().data();
```

The second signature is dangerous. It is easy to accidentally return a reference to a temporary with it. It is easy to write misleading client code where you think something got moved out but didn't. There is *one* sensible use case for returning rvalue references, and that use case was already taken care of by the standard library in the forms of `std::move` and `std::forward`.

Comment: In short, the `data(int)` is code smell 2 ways: override using magic unused type, and returning rvalue reference, both of which signal a bad method.  If you need `foo.data(0)` functionality, just `std::move(foo.data())`